# Local IIS host Wcf Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I"m facing this type of error when i'm  host WCF service in local IIS 7 
i'm getting Error

```
"<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
             Service="WcfServiceDemo.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>"
```

Please help any one.

Comment: Can you share some code or explain in more detail what the problem is? Do you have logging or a stacktrace that you can share?

Comment: Which error are you getting? How is your project/service set up? Many factors can play into this, so more information is needed to help you.

Comment: When i'm host Wcf services in local IIS afterthat browse my services then see this ""<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfServiceDemo.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>"

Comment: not getting any error only see page ""<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfServiceDemo.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %> 
when browse service

Comment: Try running the [ServiceModel Registration Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012(v=vs.110).aspx) - something might have gotten mixed up on your box and this may fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here: remove the outer set of quotes from the .svc file. I'm guessing you're seeing a literal output to the screen instead of a directive that is getting processed properly.